# How to handle int interruption in real mode? (16 bit)

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-16, bios, real-mode

I am creating an operating system since this summer, it is an 32 bits operating system which work in protected mode. I need to creat a way to make BIOS interrupt so I need to pass in real mode and before in 16bit, I sucessfully pass to 16 bit but I am not sure that I pass in real mode at the end of my code. I try by example to switch video mode but my emulator, Boch write :

```
00012417016e[CPU0 ] interrupt(real mode) vector > idtr.limit
00012417016e[CPU0 ] interrupt(real mode) vector > idtr.limit
00012417016e[CPU0 ] interrupt(real mode) vector > idtr.limit
00012417016i[CPU0 ] real mode
00012417016i[CPU0 ] CS.d_b = 16 bit
00012417016i[CPU0 ] SS.d_b = 16 bit
00012417016i[CPU0 ] | EAX=00004c00  EBX=00000123  ECX=00000000  EDX=00001034
00012417016i[CPU0 ] | ESP=0009f000  EBP=0009effc  ESI=00000123  EDI=0000ffde
00012417016i[CPU0 ] | IOPL=0 id vip codec vm RF nt of df IF tf sf zf af pf cf
00012417016i[CPU0 ] | SEG selector     base    limit G D
00012417016i[CPU0 ] | SEG sltr(index|ti|rpl)     base    limit G D
00012417016i[CPU0 ] |  CS:0000( 0004| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00012417016i[CPU0 ] |  DS:07c0( 0005| 0|  0) 00007c00 0000ffff 0 0
00012417016i[CPU0 ] |  SS:8000( 0005| 0|  0) 00080000 0000ffff 0 0
00012417016i[CPU0 ] |  ES:07c0( 0005| 0|  0) 00007c00 0000ffff 0 0
00012417016i[CPU0 ] |  FS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00012417016i[CPU0 ] |  GS:0000( 0005| 0|  0) 00000000 0000ffff 0 0
00012417016i[CPU0 ] | EIP=00001d63 (00001d63 )
00012417016i[CPU0 ] | CR0=0x00000010 CR1=0 CR2=0x00000000
00012417016i[CPU0 ] | CR3=0x00000000 CR4=0x00000000
00012417016i[CPU0 ] >> int 0x21 : CD21
00012417016e[CPU0 ] exception(): 3rd (13) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 00h, resetting
00012417016i[SYS  ] bx_pc_system_c::Reset(SOFTWARE) called
```

My assembly codee to switch in real mode is :

```
global go16
;______________________________________________________________________________________________________
;Switch to 16-bit real Mode
;IN/OUT:  nothing

go16:
    [BITS 32]
    ;cli                 ;Clear interrupts    
    pop edx             ;save return location in edx
    jmp 0x20:PM16       ;Load CS with selector 0x20
;For go to 16-bit real mode, first we have to go to 16-bit protected mode
    [BITS 16]
PM16:
    mov ax, 0x28            ;0x28 is 16-bit protected mode selector.
    mov ss, ax  
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00+0x200    ;Stack hase base at 0x7c00+0x200    

    mov eax, cr0
    mov [savcr0], eax
    and eax, 0xfffffffe     ;Clear protected enable bit in cr0
    mov cr0, eax  
    jmp 0:realMode          ;Load CS and IP

realMode:
;Load segment registers with 16-bit Values.
    mov ax, 0   
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00+0x200    
    mov ax, 0x07c0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, 0x8000
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0xf000
    lidt [idt_real]     ;Load real mode interrupt vector table
    sti
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 10h
    cli
    hlt


;Real mode interrupt vector table
idt_real:
    dw 0x3ff        ; 256 entries, 4b each = 1K
    dd 0            ; Real Mode IVT @ 0x0000
 
savcr0:
    dd 0
```

Thank you for your help, if you need some other elements ask them to me in comments
the

Comment: Make sure your `org` matches your runtime setup. In particular you seem to have `IP=1d63` but `DS=7c0`.

Comment: I think my org is correct but I don't really understand `interrupt(real mode) vector > idtr.limit` why boch write that

Comment: Because due to `org` mismatch your `lidt [idt_real]` is not accessing the IDT you have set up. You can dump the IDTR in the  bochs debugger too.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I repair this mistake?

Comment: Leaving `ds` at `0` could work, but would have to verify your whole memory layout to be sure.

Comment: Thank you a lot but where in my code I can change ds value, if I give you a git link do you think you help me more?

Comment: I change ds to 0 but now I have an other error `00002172854i[CPU0 ] BxError: instruction with opcode=0xff
00002172854i[CPU0 ] mod was c0, nnn was 7, rm was 7
00002172854i[CPU0 ] WARNING: Encountered an unknown instruction (signalling illegal instruction)
00002172861i[CPU0 ] math_abort: MSDOS compatibility FPU exception
00002172862i[CPU0 ] math_abort: MSDOS compatibility FPU exception`

Comment: Means you ended up somewhere wrong. Can't tell from this where. Maybe you corrupted the real mode IVT while you were in protected mode.